# Too many split screens opening in Emacs!

Tags: emacs, split, grep, buffer

Ever since I installed emacs on a new machine I have seen an ugly behaviour. Unfortunately, my old .emacs files are rather fragmented and I can't determine whether I used to have elisp that took care of this.

The problem is this: it used to be that when I performed a command that would open a new buffer such as grep'ing, or clicking a file name within search results, one of two things would happen:

1. If only one buffer is showing, the screen will split once
2. If more than one buffer is showing, the buffer window after the current buffer window would open the desired file

I want this behaviour back. What I am getting now is the following:

Emacs will keep splitting the window until four buffer windows are open. If I continually click multiple grep results, the buffer window where they open cycles through the three other (non-grep-results) buffer windows. I'd like it if they just kept opening in the same location: the "next" buffer window beside/below the results--same buffer window every time.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: I want this too, the new behaviour drives me nuts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider setting `split-height-threshold` to a larger value than the frame height; that will prevent unwanted vertical split.

```
(setq split-height-threshold 999)
```

If you prefer vertical split over horizontal split, customize `split-width-threshold` instead.

For more fine-grained control of how a new buffer is displayed, customize `display-buffer-function`; that will allow you to completely replace the default `display-buffer` function which dictates the buffer display policy.

Comment: Actually, setting it to `nil` is the prescribed way to disable vertical splitting… " If this is
nil, `split-window-sensibly' is not allowed to split a window
vertically. "  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: +1 for blalor's critical improvement on this answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've been using for a while:

```
;;;---------------------------------------------------------------------
;;; display-buffer

;; The default behaviour of `display-buffer' is to always create a new
;; window. As I normally use a large display sporting a number of
;; side-by-side windows, this is a bit obnoxious.
;;
;; The code below will make Emacs reuse existing windows, with the
;; exception that if have a single window open in a large display, it
;; will be split horisontally.

(setq pop-up-windows nil)

(defun my-display-buffer-function (buf not-this-window)
  (if (and (not pop-up-frames)
           (one-window-p)
           (or not-this-window
               (not (eq (window-buffer (selected-window)) buf)))
           (> (frame-width) 162))
      (split-window-horizontally))
  ;; Note: Some modules sets `pop-up-windows' to t before calling
  ;; `display-buffer' -- Why, oh, why!
  (let ((display-buffer-function nil)
        (pop-up-windows nil))
    (display-buffer buf not-this-window)))

(setq display-buffer-function 'my-display-buffer-function)
```

Comment: Works for me. One caveat is that it does't pay attention to compile-mode frames and keeps them open while closing other, more important ones.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this when switching from emacs 22 to 23.

I found that setting `display-buffer-reuse-frames` to non-nil (as suggested by the help for `display-buffer`) helped, if you already have a file open in a buffer.